# Sending signalfd to another process

Tags: linux, signals, ipc

Process A sends a signalfd to process B. What will happen when B attempts to read()? If B adds the signalfd to an epoll, when will epoll_wait return?

Comment: Show the source code which makes you ask the question.

Comment: Please explain how do you send the file descriptor obtained with `signalfd` to another process. So edit your question to improve it.

Comment: -1, since you did not improve your question.

Comment: +1 question is unambiguous as-is and is an interesting question (one I'm trying to answer for myself). The method by which the FD is passed between processes is not relevant and would only add noise to the question. Another possible way is by inheritance from parent to child.

Comment: @kenton-varda signalfd `read()` works on the signal queue on the current thread. I have no idea about epoll, but poll and select will use the current thread's signal queue.

Comment: @HristoVenev: Yeah, I think epoll is what is confusing me. I think that epoll will decide readiness based on signals to the process that added the signalfd to the epoll (which makes sense implementation-wise but is inconsistent). Currently testing, then will post an answer for other people to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a clue in the man page:

> **fork(2) semantics**
>
> After a fork(2), the child inherits a copy of the signalfd file descriptor.  A read(2) from the file  descriptor  in  the  child will return information about signals queued to the child.

`signalfd`s transferred via unix socket should behave the same as those inherited by `fork()`. Basically, it's irrelevant which process created the `signalfd`; `read()`ing from it always returns signals queued to the process that calls `read()`.

There is a weird interaction with `epoll`, however: Since the `epoll` event queue is managed outside the context of any particular process, it decides the readiness of the `signalfd` based on the process which originally called `epoll_ctl()` to register interest in the `signalfd`. So if you arrange to watch a `signalfd` with an `epoll` FD, and then send both FDs to another process, the receiving process will see inconsistent results: `epoll` will signal readiness only when the sending process has a signal, but `signalfd` will return signals for the receiving process.

This situation is particularly easy to get into using `fork()`. For example, if you initialize an event loop library than uses `epoll` and `signalfd`, then call `fork()` (e.g. to daemonize the process), then try to use the library in the child process, you may find you cannot receive signals. (I spent all day yesterday trying to debug such a problem.)

Answer (score -1):

This is inconsistent, or at least an under-documented corner-case. Read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

A process A could send a *signal* (not a signalfd) using [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) or [killpg(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html) to a process B.

The process B is handling a signal (and there are some default behavior to handle some signals). It could install (in a POSIX-ly standardized way) a signal handler using old [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) or newer [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), or it could ask (in a Linux specific way) by using [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) to get some data on a file descriptor.

<sup>So `signalfd` gives on success a fresh file descriptor, like `open` or `socket` do.</sup>

Read the `signalfd(2)` documentation, it explains what is happening on B side when it reads (the kernel is sending some `struct signalfd_siginfo`, I imagine from the point of view of the process getting the signal, not of the process reading the file descriptor, see kernel's source file [fs/signalfd.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/signalfd.c)), or waits with `poll` or *epoll* on the file descriptor given by `signalfd` ; the polling will succeed when a signal has been received by B.

A successful `signalfd` is just getting an *opened file descriptor* (like the file descriptors `open`, `socket`, `accept`, `pipe` are giving you) and you won't share that file descriptor with unrelated processes.

I won't make any supposition on what happens if you dare sending that file descriptor using [`sendmsg(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) on a [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket using `SCM_RIGHTS` to some other process. I guess it would be similar to [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s or [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html)-s. But I certainly won't do that: `signalfd` is Linux specific, and you are in an *undocumented* corner-case situation. Read the kernel source code to understand what is happening, or ask on [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/). And don't expect too much future kernels to behave consistently with present ones on that undocumented aspect ...

Comment: Because I want to know what happens if a signalfd created in one process is sent to another process and used there. In the documentation `read(2)` returns signalfd_siginfo for 'the process'. Is it the calling process or the process that created the signalfd?